# Method not found in cordova.js

Tags: javascript, android, cordova, plugins

I included **info.asankan.phonegap.smsplugin.smsplugin** plugin for my project in Android and I do have cordova.js in assets/www folder, and I copied all its java file in src folder. Still when I try to access

```
var smsplugin = cordova.require("info.asankan.phonegap.smsplugin.smsplugin");
```

It gives me error of method not found in ..//cordova.js.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: have you installed smsplugin

Comment: yes i did install the plugin @pareshm ..

Comment: Did you try [another SMS plugin](https://github.com/cordova-sms/cordova-sms-plugin)? This is a strange way to require Cordova dependencies

Comment: @dloeda i need plugin to read sms not send send for OTP ..